# SP2016 Central Admin error: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FixServerConfirmation'

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2016, central-administration, sharepoint-farm, farm-setup

I have just set up SharePoint 2016 On-Premise on a single server farm (dev environment) in my organisation (I have also installed feature pack 2). Everything is set up central admin up and running but I get an error when clicking on "Manage servers in this farm" under System Settings.

This is the error:

DataBinding: `'System.Data.DataRowView'` does not contain a property with the name `'FixServerConfirmation'.`

[image]

What is this error about? I temporarily switched on verbose logging and when I clicked on Manage Servers in this farm the following events are logged in the trace logs:

```
08/16/2018 14:15:31.11  w3wp.exe (0x2510)                           0x1A24  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRowView' does not contain a property with the name 'FixServerConfirmation'.    at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.GetPropertyValue(Object container, String propName)     at System.Web.UI.DataBinder.Eval(Object container, String[] expressionParts)     at ASP._admin_topologyview_ascx.__DataBinding__control19(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()     at System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowInde... d450859e-a1b0-4049-50aa-694958965419

08/16/2018 14:15:31.11* w3wp.exe (0x2510)                           0x1A24  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...x, Int32 dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[] fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SPGridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable data)     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound()     at System.Web.UI.WebCon...  d450859e-a1b0-4049-50aa-694958965419

08/16/2018 14:15:31.11* w3wp.exe (0x2510)                           0x1A24  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...trols.CompositeDataBoundControl.CreateChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.EnsureChildControls()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   d450859e-a1b0-4049-50aa-694958965419
```

Comment: did you run the PSconfig wizard after installing the Feature Pack 2?

Comment: i ran the psconfig command: "psconfig -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b". Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: No, if you ran the config wizard via gui or not? The command u mentioned will not completely configured it

Answer (score 0):

Apologies i have found a resolution while digging a little deeper. I found another version of the psconfig script i should have ran:

PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

Thanks Waqas for putting me on the right path.